# Flask The system cannot find the path specified: '130.127.5.9'

Tags: python, flask

I've just started experimenting with flask and
I am trying to list a network driver using it. This is the command that I type on my browser. But I get an error that it cant find the path
http://127.0.0.1:5000/130.13.5.8/D/dir/

The function works for local drivers without an issue

I know why it fails. It needs 2 '\' before the actual ip or 4 '\\' .
But when I try http://127.0.0.1:5000/////130.13.5.8/D/dir/
it doesnt work. 
I even tried %F%F it also doesn't seem to do the trick.

```py
@app.route('/<path:filepath>/dir/')
def get_dir(filepath):
    dir_listing = ''
    for entry in os.listdir(filepath):
        entry_type = 'dir' if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(filepath, entry)) else 'file'
        dir_listing += '{entry_name}|{entry_type}|'.format(entry_name=entry, entry_type=entry_type)
    return dir_listing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue my workaround is the following

```py
   from ipaddress import ip_address
    try:
        ip_address(filepath.split('/')[0])
        filepath = '\\\\{filepath}'.format(filepath=filepath)
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
```